# how to trigger the woocommerce product gallery lightbox to open using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying bind a click listener to something which will open the woocommerce product gallery lightbox view.

Basically I want to re-create the functionality of the click on that little magnifying glass icon: (top right)

[image: See the icon?]

I am able to use jQuery to trigger the click event for that element...

```
$('body').on('click', '.myElems', function(){
    $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger").click();
});
```

... and this works well enough. But there's something unsettling about relying on the existence of this other element and then virtually clicking on it.

Is there a way to open the lightbox up with a function call?

--

My example uses jQuery for convenience since this is wordpress, but vanilla JS answers are fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am currently stuck on the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up using the hacky method form my question.

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck for a while with this issue.
I have found out that there is a click trigger with href = #tab-description , I think to open the product description.
So if you

```
jQuery("a:not('a[href$=\"tab-description\"]')").click(function (e) {

// Any Click event that is not tab-description

}
```

You can edit the selector inside the jQuery() to suit your use case.  but this will need some more handling as it will be triggered on menu clicks, in this case you will have to handle more conditions you can use unload idn if you want your js to execute before leaving the page